# Git: How to understand the 'git branch -a --merged master' listing?

Tags: git, git-branch

When on master branch I executed the following commands:

```
git fetch
git branch -a --merged master
```

I got the following listing:

```
$ git branch -a --merged master
  branch1
  branch2
* master
  remotes/origin/branch1
  remotes/origin/branch4
  remotes/origin/branch3
```

Can I understand from this listing that branch1 was merged and pushed to the remote master branch?

I emphasize the main point which interests me: was it also pushed to the master branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As context and reminder:

- Commits in Git are a linked list, every commit contains the hash of their parent(s)
- Branches are label to specific commits (under the hood, a branch is a file with as name the branch's name and as content the hash of the commit it points to

The command `git branch -a --merged master` gives you all the branches (local and remote, from the `-a` option, `--all`) which are accessible from ("merged in") `master` (from the `--merged master` option). That means all the branches which points to commits which are ancestors (parents/grand parents/...) of master.

The term `--merged` is slightly misleading as it does not necessarily mean that the branches have been merged (with merge commit and so on) in master.

EDIT:
From your question in the comments:

> I want to know if my local branches were already merged to remote master and pushed to remote repository.

Are your branches merged to remote master:

```
git branch --merged origin/master # Here do your branches appear?
```

Are your branches pushed to the remote repository:

```
git branch -r # Here do your branches appear?
git branch -v # This will show your for each branch if they are ahead, behind or both. This works only if their upstream is set.
```

For more info: `man git-branch`.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand whether those branches 1,3 and 4 are "pushed" into remote master. Maybe if I could understand better the differences between push and merge...

Comment: These are two very different things. You merge a branch `A` in another one (`B`), so that `B` contains the changes of `A`. You push a branch to a remote repository, so that it becomes available to other developers who clone(d) the project. One does not imply the other, they are completely unrelated.

Comment: Thank you for your time. So again, the command I used shows "merges", am I correct? So, what shows "pushes"? Is pushing a branch to a remote master necessarily means is was also pushed to remote repository? My understanding is that it is. Am I correct?

Comment: What exactly do you want to see? the branches pushed to the remote? If so, `git branch -a` shows the local and remote branches of your project. `git branch -r` shows only the remote branches.

Comment: I want to know if my local branches were already merged to remote master and pushed to remote repository.

Comment: Thank you so much!